# How to implement a custom copy property with ARC on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to implement a custom property with automatic reference counting on iOS.

My `.h` file:

```
@interface AObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString* str;
@end
```

My `.m` file:

```
@implementation AObject

@synthesize str = _str;

-(void)setStr:(NSString *)str {
    if (![_str isEqualToString:str]) {
       // Which one is right?
        _str = [str copy];   //(1)
        _str = str;          //(2)
    }
}

@end
```

Which of the two lines (1) and (2) should I use? I tested both, and both seemed to work. Is there a difference?

Comment: Your if statement is missing its closing }. Can you add it in the correct place to clear up any ambiguities?

Answer (score 3):

ARC would only automatically do retaining, not copying. If you would like it to be copied, so (1) is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

`_str = [str copy];` is correct. The reason to `copy` instead of `retain` (ARC is impliciting retaining the object for you) is because `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`. This means that `str` could be an `NSMutableString` and could later change its' value which is probably not what you want. There's no performance implications for using `copy` because if `str` is a non-mutable `NSString` then `copy` will not create another copy, it will simply increase the retain count.

Answer (score 2):

What Benedict says in specific answer to your question is correct (+1), but you have another minor "issue".

```
if (![_str isEqualToString:str])
```

is overkill. You might as well do

```
if (_str != str)
```

which is a much faster comparison and only leads to a significant penalty if `str` is a mutable string that compares equal to `_str`.